# How to deal with Python long import

Tags: python, python-import

This is about python long import like this:

from aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee.fff.ggg.hhh.iii.jjj.kkk.lll.mmm.nnn.ooo import xxx

The length between 'from' and 'import' is already above than 80 characters, is there any better pythonic ways to deal with it?

Comment: I have yet to see an import anywhere near that long. Is this a real situation you're encountering?

Comment: Where are you doing this import from? You can potentially use a relative import. e.g. `from .mmm.nnn.ooo import xxx`. Also, if this is a real thing, I'd suggest that some thought about your file structure/project layout might be more important.

Comment: I sometime use long import like `from aaa.bbb import ccc, ddd, fff, ...` but only because I don't like to write a line for each stuff that I import. But I have never see 14 level of sub modules, some must be wrong there...

Comment: Just add #NoQA to the end and move on, it's not the end of the world.

Comment: There's no love lost in having a line that's longer than 80 chars, as PEP-8 is _only_ a suggested style guide. A good one, but in this case I feel you should be allowed to have a longer line. Readability counts too.

Comment: Yes, it is a real situation. Import from an internal framework that is developed by others and I don't want to touch it. I was trying to use relative import, it works but complained by pylint saying that 'Unable to import'. Thanks guys for the advice. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always wrap lines using the `\` character at the end of the line.

```
from a.very.long.and.unconventional.structure.\
         and.name import foo
```

For multiple statements to import after the `from x import` statement, you can use parentheses and wrap inside these parentheses without a newline escape:

```
from foo.bar import (test,
                     and,
                     others)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @languitar. I would like to use \ character.